# Adding labels on lines with pyqtgraph

Tags: python-3.x, label, line, curve, pyqtgraph

Is there any way to plot [labels on curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qdtc.png) with pyqtgraph?
Examples are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Pyqtgraph does not provide any such functionality out of the box as matplotlib does.